# Show code in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to produce a flexdashboard with R and want to show code in my presentation, but this seems not to work. 
Here a little example:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

### Code

```{r, eval=FALSE, include=TRUE}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```   

### Output

```{r, fig.align='center', echo = FALSE}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

[image]

Even other chuck options like `fig.show = 'hide'` will not work.
Is it possible to show code in a R-chuck in flexdashboard?
The code highlights would be a benefit instead of a plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both the code and plot to show set the chunk options to: `echo = true`

If you just want code set it to: `echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE`

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

### Code

```{r, echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```   

### Code and Plot

```{r, echo=TRUE}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
``` 

### Plot

```{r, fig.align='center', echo = FALSE}
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

Answer (score 3):

It won't show as a panel in your presentation, but to add a `</> Source Code` button to your dashboard, include `source_code: embed` in your YAML.

`---
title: "Example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    source_code: embed
---`